# If I destroy a TFS project, can I create a new one with the same name later?

Tags: tfs

I am inheriting a TFS system with a bunch of unused projects already created, they are not needed currently nor planned for a future time. They have no work items created or source code checked in so I'd like to destroy them to get rid of overhead and wasted space. I want to be sure though, if for whatever reason later on we need a new project named the same as one of these will I be able to create it? Or will I need ot remember this list and change the name slightly in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if you want to get rid of all TFS and the project, you can firt uninstall TFS like a normal program and then remove de TFS databases. and resintall all. It works for me :D

Comment: Sory I wasn't that clear Ryblex. I don't want to get rid of all of TFS there are still 10 or 12 valid functioning projects. It's just 30 other projects that seem to have have been created for no apparent reason.

Comment: so you want to delete those projects, Im not pretty sure but when you "Delete" a project from TFS, it doesn't really deleted from TFS database, so you have to do it by hand

Comment: That is true Ryblex, unless you destroy the project, which supposedly removes all references to it. However, I would like to make sure in case we do need to reuse one of those names at a future point. Because if I can not reuse them, then I will only delete them so I can undelete at a later time.